# What is the impact on not using volumes in my docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker, what a wonderful tool!. Following the Django tutorial, their docs provide a basic `docker-compose.yml`, that looks similar to the following one that I've created.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    command: python manage.py migrate
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: my_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_secret_pass!
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

However, in every single docker-compose file that I see around, the following is added:

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

What are those volumes used for? Does it mean that if I now restart my postgres container all my data is deleted, but if I had the volumes it is not?

Is my `docker-compose.yml` ready for production?

Comment: Basically yes, if you `docker-compose down` then the containers are removed and if there is data inside, it is also destroyed. Using volume mount helps it persist between container instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are those volumes used for?

Volumes persist data from your container to your Docker host.

This:

```
volumes:
  - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

means that `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your container will be persisted in `./postgres-data` in your Docker host.

What @Dan Lowe commented is correct, if you do `docker-compose down` without volumes, all the data insisde your containers will be lost, but if you have `volumes` the directories, and files you specified will be kept in your Docker host

You can see this data in your Docker host in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<your_volume_name>/_data` even after your container don't exist anymore.